# Laravel Pass Parameter from Route to Filter

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4, mamp

I am using the laravel framework.
If I have the following route:

```
Route::get('/test/{param}', array('before'=>'test_filter', 'SomeController@anyAction'));
```

And this filter:

```
Route::filter('test_filter', function() {
    $param = [Get the parameter from the url];
    return "The value is $param";
});
```

How can I pass parameters to the filter so that when visiting /test/foobar I would get a page saying: "The value is foobar"?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Filters can be passed parameters, like the Route object or the Request:

Specifying Filter Parameters

```
Route::filter('age', function($route, $request, $value)
{
    //
});
```

Above example is taken from the docs: http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters

Once you're inside the closure, you take the parameter from the `$route`:

```
Route::filter('test_filter', function($route) {
    $param = $route->getParameter('param'); // use the key you defined
    return "The value is $param";
});
```

---

Alternatively, I believe you can just fetch the segment you need (not tested but should work):

```
Route::filter('test_filter', function() {
    $param = Request::segment(1);
    return "The value is $param";
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "inside the closure"?

Comment: Uhm, I'm no english native speaker, so I might not be expressing well...I mean, in the body of the function you pass as second argument of filter; what you're already doing, i.e. , don't pay much attention to my bad wording :)

Comment: Thanks sorry for not getting that in the first place

Comment: Just what I was looking for.

Comment: @DamienPirsy - you say "// use the key you defined" - where I have to define the key? I am not able to get value of parameter

Comment: Found that it works this way: $route->getParameter('one'); - one means the first parameter after the method name in url. For example example.com/shops-list/index/paramterOne - parameterOne will be the value in this case.
What if I don't want it to be in url?