# how to pass arguments to filter in laravel4.2

Tags: laravel-4

in my project , i want to pass 'user_id' to filter to check.

this is isAdmin function:

```
public function isAdmin($id){
    $user=User::find($id);
    if($user->role==10){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and this is my route file:

```
Route::group(array('before'=>'admin'),function(){
    Route::get('dashboard','UserController@Dashboard');
});
```

this is my filte that iwant give user_id ($id), and idont know how.

```
Route::filter('admin',function($id)
{
    if(Auth::guest() or ! Auth::user()->isAdmin($id))
        return Redirect::guest('user/logout');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case, you can directly check from the filter like this:

```
Route::filter('admin',function()
{
    if(Auth::guest() or Auth::user()->role != 10)
        return Redirect::guest('user/logout');
});
```

You do not need to pass params.

Also have a look to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790922/laravel-pass-parameter-from-route-to-filter) if you really want to pass params.

Link of Laravel Doc: [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters)